# Installing Linux distro on PogoplugPro

Tags: linux, system-installation, arch-arm

I have a PogoplugPro and I want to install a Linux distro on it.  However, none of the tutorials I have found cover the model I have:

```
Model: POGOPLUG PRO
BusyBox v1.16.1 (2010-11-30 12:06:37 PST) multi-call binary.
uname -a
    Linux PogoplugPro 2.6.31.6_SMP_820 #96 SMP Tue Feb 8 10:06:27 PST 2011 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I have tried optware but I want to boot a "real" distro, replacing the on-board OS.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: After looking at a few forum posts I convinced myself that ArchLinux ARM(http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/pogoplug-provideov3) was the right thing to try even though the exact model is not listed on the website.  I gave it a try and it almost worked the first time.  The only problem I had was with the USB drive I was using didn't format properly so I had to put it on another Linux box I have and reload it which was not too bad at all.  Thanks ArchLinux.

Comment: I rebooted the Pogoplug and now it does not boot.  I did do some package management using `pacman` including doing an upgrade that had some errors.  I will reinstall the software and try again.